# WP-API user email change confirmation

Tags: wp-api, email-verification

I am developing an android client for wordpress website using wp-api and jwt plugin.
By default, wordpress did not send an email confirmation when the user changes his email from control panel.
I was able to solve this issue using the code provided [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41730/confirmation-required-on-email-change/47878#47878).

However, when I change the email using a post request to the api route /users/id, I didn't got any confirmation email.

another problem is that wp-api didn't has any route for new user registration as the route /users requires authentication for create operation، so I had to make a new route for user creation with no authentication required using register_new_user() and I got the confirmation email when new user registered as a confirmation link but I need something that I can use in my android app like a confirmation code for example....any idea how to solve those problems?

Answer (score 1):

> wp-api didn't has any route for new user registration as the route
>   /users requires authentication for create operation

As far as I know, using proper authentication (I'm using JWT), rest API ***does let*** you create new users.
The problem is that if you go that way, you have to implement your own mail-verifcation system, since no confirmation mail is sent.

(See my answer to this: [Authentication for a mobile app connected via wp-rest api?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221136/authentication-for-a-mobile-app-connected-via-wp-rest-api/301124#301124))